# Does visual studio 2010 unlimited modeling project do reverse engineering?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-generation, uml, reverse-engineering, modeling

Does visual studio 2010 unlimited modeling project do reverse engineering? How about code generation from the UML models? I am playing around with it and it makes beautiful UML class diagram but I can't find any options to create code templates based on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following links:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsarch/thread/a1ee9393-8f9b-45f2-8277-6e49346a119a

[Sneak peek at the first “Feature Pack” for VS2010 Visualization and Modeling Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/camerons/archive/2010/03/19/announcing-the-first-feature-pack-for-vs2010-visualization-and-modeling-tools.aspx)

[Visualization and Modeling Feature Pack (MSDN Subscribers Only)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff655021.aspx)

- **Generate code from UML class diagrams.**
- Create UML class diagrams from code. Import UML class, sequence, and use case elements from XMI 2.1 files.
- Create and view links from work items to model elements.
- Generate dependency graphs for ASP.NET Web, C, and C++ projects.
- Create and validate layer diagrams for C and C++ code.
- Write custom code to create, modify, and validate layer diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

> Does visual studio 2010 unlimited modeling project do reverse engineering?

VS2010 allows you to reverse engineer from code to UML diagrams. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140255%28office.10%29.aspx)

> How about code generation?

Again refer to MSDN [Visual Studio Code Generation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx)